# How to tune read lock in BDB transaction

Tags: performance, transactions, berkeley-db

I have posted one thread https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10459458&#10459458, but no answer is there.

again, from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/programmer_reference/transapp_tune.html

> **read locks** Performing all read operations outside of transactions or
>   at Degrees of isolation can often significantly increase application
>   throughput. In addition, limiting the lifetime of non-transactional
>   cursors will reduce the length of times locks are held, thereby
>   improving concurrency.

so with TDS, I wonder if I don't give transaction while read data from databases?
and can performance benefit from this process?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds correct. Have you tried building a unit test to compare?